# TensorFlow 2.5.0 incompatibility with NumPy 1.21+? (2021-10-05)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow2.0

To everyone who stumbles upon this:

I was recently doing image classification (fit a CNN onto some labeled data) and I wanted to do data augmentation using keras's modules.  However, I get thrown a NotImplementedError.  More specifically, it says the following verbatim:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (sequential_3/sequential/random_rotation/rotation_matrix/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Here's what I coded for my augmentation layer:

```
angle = 15
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(angle/360)
])
```

So I wanted a horizontal flip of all my images and a random rotation by 15 degrees.  I directly plugged this into my CNN:

```
layers_2 = [
    #image augmentation layer
    data_augmentation,
    
    #convolution layer
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    
    #dropout for regularization
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    #MLP layer
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')
]

model_2 = keras.Sequential(layers_2)

model_2.compile(optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics = [tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
)

epochs_2 = 15

#fitting

history_2 = model_2.fit(
    normalized_train_ds,
    validation_data = normalized_val_ds,
    epochs = epochs_2
)
```

Where *normalized_train_ds* and *normalized_val_ds* are both normalized tensorflow.data.Dataset objects.

**Necessary context**: I am running this on my local machine, in a Python 3.9.7-configured environment.  My NumPy version is 1.21.2 and my TensorFlow version is 2.5.0.  There have been similar issues to mine back in February 2021, except they noticed the same issue with someone running Python 3.9.1 and TensorFlow 2.4.1, with NumPy 1.20+ (link to that issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47360).

**Actual Question**: Did I just write some bad code, or are my versions of Python, TensorFlow, NumPy not compatible?  I tried installing a previous version of numpy (1.20+) but it throws me the same issue.  If I run this on google Colab notebooks, this ceases to be an issue.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Tensorflow 2.6.0 seems to be compatible with 1.19.5 or lower

Comment: I checked it and this was resolved in `TF2.7` and `tf-nightly`.

Answer (score 2):

According to this issue on github, tensorflow 2.5 and numpy 1.20+ are not compatible.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47691

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Agree this was an issue with `TF2.5` or before. But, this was resolved recently.

With `TF2.7` and `tf-nightly`, I successfully trained some models that had this numpy incompatibility issue. You can also check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L86) that `master` branch now requires 'numpy >= 1.20'.

Also, check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47691) GitHub issue that was resolved. Thanks!